# Converting map payoad to json payload in mule

Tags: json, dictionary, mule, dataweave

I have output from  my data weaver is a map like below

```
[{"LNUMBER":9192428,"INUMBER":005RPS}]
```

But while sending this payload to api I want to have a json payload without [] like below

```
{"LNUMBER":9192428,"INUMBER":005RPS}
```

What is the best way I  can achieve this in mule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you cannot do it in your dataweave trasformation you can simply put in payload the first element of the map and than use object to json transformer:

```
<set-payload value="#[payload[0]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
```

Off course this will work only for the case you have a map containing always only one element.
I would aniway suggest you to see if you can do it directly in dataweave it will probally make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

hi please add application/json in the palce of application/java it will convert all your data into json paylaod

inside transform message  %dw 1.0

### %output application/java to json